# Infinite Loop a Handler to classify images

Tags: android, android-camera, handler, infinite-loop

I need to classify an images recorded by my camera as often as possible in a infinite loop. Every classification takes about 0.5 seconds. 
What is the best way to implement this in android?

So far I tried to add a Handler inside `onCreate`, but it seems I cannot just call my method from there:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    mHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("myLog","run was called");
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            TakeScreenshot(); // <-- this is my method which doesn't work 
        }
    };

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);

}
```

The method `TakeScreenshot();` is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921128/take-a-picture-with-camera-and-get-bitmap?lq=1). I basically need to modify it such that it takes a screenshot as often as it can instead of only after pressing the button.

Comment: A `Handler`, perhaps? What have you tried?

Comment: I added my current code to the question

Comment: Why it does not work? Is in other class and not static or what?

Comment: Where did you define the `TakeScreenshot()` method? If it is in the Activity, you should be able to call it.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `run` function, or even in your `TakeScreenshot()` function does the breakpoint hit? if neither hit, at least we know where it is breaking. I suppose we need to know what is not working, is there an error?

Comment: Thanks @Krum110487 . I guess the error is indeed inside `TakeScreenshot();`. It's calling for some non global variables. I try to fix that and let you know if it runs