# Android Camera TakePicture not called on some phone (HTC One X)

Tags: android, android-camera

I have notice that some Android Devices can call mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null , new JpegPictureCallback()); to trigger a callback but some cannot.

(All devices that I used for test are at least android 4.0)

For an example, I tested this on the google nexus s, nexus 4, and droid razer hd phone. This three phone gets a call back for mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null , new JpegPictureCallback());

However, my HTC One X phone do not trigger this call back.

Does anyone know why some phone such as HTC One X do not trigger a call back for mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null , new JpegPictureCallback()); ? and is there any walk around for this?

thanks and appreciate any comments and opinions.

Comment: i had issues where if i did not set onPreviewCallback to null, takePicture would fail, but it would crash. does your app crash or just not callback?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250719/android-camera-jpeg-call-back-picture-data-null

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing same issue. After lot of research , hit and trial I have fixed the issue.Problem was that some phone does not return the callback if camera property is set to HDR ie`setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR)`. Event though I have  set it only after checking whether HDR property is supported or not.So I only removed HDR property  and everything is working.

Conclusion : For some phone some specific camera property may not work.And also report such issue to manufacture if possible.