# Raw pictures support with android L

Tags: android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

We are looking for a method retrieving the raw image from an android device camera.

As far as we've search we did not find any sufficient method for it.

Is there any method for doing that?

We read that the upcoming Android L new API should publish new methods for doing just that. Does anyone know if it is a part of the preview release?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Impossible to obtain RAW image data from camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514862/android-impossible-to-obtain-raw-image-data-from-camera)

Comment: We saw some threads about it, as we wrote - we searched about it before posting this question.
We just want to know if raw capture was released in the android L preview.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write DNG files using the newly introduced Camera2 API. Works only on Nexus 5 so far though.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find it?